# Configurable static tab in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams

I have developed a SharePoint WebPart that I want to use in my Teams. In this WebPart I can hot-swapping several properties: width, height... but when I try to use this WebPart in Teams, I can't customize this properties and is a necessary thing.

In the manifest file, I have declared a staticTab because I need to pin the icon in the left menu.

```
"staticTabs": [
    {
      "entityId": "example",
      "name": "exampleName",
      "contentUrl": "https://{teamSiteDomain}/_layouts/15/TeamsLogon.aspx?SPFX=true&dest=/_layouts/15/teamshostedapp.aspx%3FopenPropertyPane=true%26teams%26personal%26componentId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%26forceLocale={locale}",
      "scopes": [
        "personal"
      ]
    }
  ],
```

Somebody know how I could have a static tab and customize the properties?

---

On the other hand, If I try, from the the catalog, to click on "sync button between SP & Teams" it doesn't works.

[image]

Kind regards!

Comment: Did you added the sharepoint site url in validDomain[] list of app manifest?

Comment: Customize is not possible within Teams, a SPFx webpart synced with Teams as Tab, You can customize the webpart from sharepoint and sync the webpart with Teams.

Comment: Hi @Trinetra-MSFT, thanks for your reply. How can I sync the WebPart with Teams?. I have the manifest file, but If I try to click on the sync button, it never works

Comment: You need to upload your webpart sppkg  package which is created while building webpart into sharepoint app catalog, there you will see sync with Teams option if you browse option in app catalog

Comment: Hi @Trinetra-MSFT, these option doesn't work in my catalog

Comment: Do you have admin access for your sharepoint catalog?

Comment: Customization of SPFx webparts within Teams Tab is not possible, you can customize or edit in sharepoint itself

Comment: Hi @Trinetra-MSFT. In this case I have another doubt. When I try to change the values in SharePoint, these changes don't apply in Teams. What can I do?

Comment: No, Once you edit your SPFx webpart in sharepoint you can use sync with teams option(if you can see it), it will reflect in Teams tab unless you are making your changes in code than you need to upload your sppkg in app catalog and use sync with Teams option

Comment: Ok, one last thing, this option: sync with teams. In my case always return: Error 500. I have been researching and a lot of people have problems with this function. Could you give me a clue about the way to solve this error?